# Capacitors for PWM Motor Control

Tags: arduino, capacitor, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller

I am planning a Rev2 of a previously successful motor driver PCB and I want to simplify it.

Rev1 was a bit 'belt and braces'. It took 24V from a main board and passed that through an adjustable switching voltage regulator PCB assembly, an Amazon off-the-shelf job which inserted by header pins and was there to support reusability and modularity. That VOut then went to a motor (I use 5, 12 and 24V in my project); down to an IRF540N MOSFET driven by Arduino PWM (0.5 or 1 kHz) and then to Ground.

The schematic is attached. You'll also see bits like a switch to bypass the voltage regulator, fuses, flyback diodes, standard resistors around the MOSFET, and a DPDT latching relay acting as an H-Bridge. They're incidental to the question I think.

[image: Rev 1 - with both voltage regulator and MOSFET]

Rev2 I was considering combining the MOSFET and the Voltage Regulator as they're basically the same concept. I know that motors generally are pretty resilient against high-frequency voltage variation but I was wondering if the motor would cope with being PWM'd at a peak voltage of multiple times its rated voltage with a suitably low duty cycle.

If it's better practice to smooth it out, I was thinking about putting capacitors in, one between VCC and MOSFET Drain and another between VCC and MOSFET Source. Back-of-the-envelope suggests that to keep fluctuation around +-10% would take 500uF of capacitance (dV = 2V, dT = 1ms, I ~ 1A with 24V, 50% duty cycle @ 500 Hz). Simplified schematic (less fuse, bypass switch and relay) attached. Inductor/resistor pair represents motor.

I also wonder if I'd cause any weird side effects with the MOSFET by doing that, or any other weird side effects I haven't considered. P.S. any other feedback welcome!

[image: Rev 2 - without voltage reg, adding caps around MOSFET]

Comment: Your schematic is hard to read when you have "dumb boxes" for components with just their pins listed. Please consider a schematic symbol for a fuse when you have a fuse and a switch when you have a switch. I can't see why you would want to regulated the voltage to your motor unless you are otherwise exceeding the max rating for the motor. Also, there is a diode missing across the coil of the relay.

Comment: Hi Winny, I accept the point about 'dumb boxes'. In this case it's because the schematic was used as a PCB layout schematic rather than a simulation schematic and the required footprints had to be imported. However the fuse and the switch are incidental.

The VCC coming from the board is 24V and I use a mix of 5, 12 and 24V motors. Also I'd like to be able to vary their speed.

Ref the 'missing' diode, it's a DPDT latching relay so we can't have a diode there; the coil needs to be able to be activated in both directions.

Comment: The older and more experienced you get, the more effort you will end up putting into your schematics and demanding the same from others in my experience. I was too using the schematic just as a stepping stone to get to the layout in the past. Oh! Latching. Do you swap the polarity to make it go back? Do you have a 5V motor with 24V input which you wish to limit?

Comment: I've updated the schematics and removed the incidentals.

Yes, I swap the polarity to reverse the relay. The pins are driven by a BJT H-bridge on the main board which reverses all 4 of these motor cards at the same time.

Yes, I have 5V and 12V motors I want to drive with a 24V line. It's designed to be modular, in case I wanted to use a different motor in future, hence the need to regulate down. However the Rev1 with an upstream switching reg to lower voltage plus MOSFET downstream for additional speed control, was OTT and I was thinking about ways to combine the functions.

Comment: Ah! Then it becomes a little bit more complicated. You can see your motor winding as an inductor for your buck converter it effectively is but you are subjecting it to more voltage than intended for. This could be a standard problem and the voltage rating of the motor is more of a max speed and/or power than max instantaneous voltage. Ask the manufacturer or test it yourself and see if you can live with the risk. If yes, you can omit the voltage regulator.

Comment: Thanks for all your engagement. What I'd come back round to, though, is whether capacitors around the MOSFET would help - could I run a 12V motor off a 24V supply using 50% PWM if I was to use caps to try to keep the voltage oscillation to +- 10%?

Comment: Hi Josh, the schematic you added earlier was explaining your idea well. Now both pictures are the same. Can you add that back.

Comment: Hi Norman, I changed the pictures at Winny's request. But they aren't the same - the top one uses a voltage regulator and the bottom one adds capacitors on either side of the MOSFET.